# Why does Python 3 code run on Python 2, at all?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a small shopping list program designed to run on Python 3. I assumed my Mac was running Python 3 and tried to run the file. It seemed to work well as long as I surrounded my input strings with quotation marks, otherwise I got a NameError. This is not needed in Python 3.

Why did the code run at all? I know that functions such as print() are written differently in Python 2 so why didn't it fail from the get-go?

```python3
# List Creation
shopping_list = []

# Help
def show_help():
    print("""
Add items to the list when promted. 
To end the list type 'DONE'.
To view the list type 'SHOW'.
To view this help prompt, type 'HELP'.
""")

show_help()

# View
def view_list():
    print(shopping_list)

while True:
    new_item = input("> ")
    if new_item.upper() == 'DONE':
        break
    elif new_item.upper() == 'HELP':
        show_help()
        continue
    elif new_item.upper() == 'SHOW':
        view_list()
        continue
    shopping_list.append(new_item)
print(shopping_list)
```

Comment: print('Hello') and print 'Hello' are valid python statements in Py2.

Comment: Yikes. Sorry. I'm editing it right away.

Comment: @FlyingTeller He means if he types `"foo"`, the string `"foo"` is returned, while `foo` by itself results in a `NameError` because Python 2's `input` tries to evaluate the name `foo`.

Comment: Just for fun (further reading): [here's](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) a cheat sheet for writing code that works with both versions, in case you ever need to do that, or want to better understand what you can and can't do in each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of Python 3 code runs in Python 2 because Python was specifically designed to make that true.

---

`print` is a bit of a special case—simple `print`s of a single variable do the same thing in both languages, but more complex `print`s may not. How does this work?

In Python 3, `print(shopping_list)` is a call to the `print` function with a single argument, `shopping_list`.

In Python 2, `print(shopping_list)` is a print statement with one printable, the value `(shopping_list)`, which is of course the same value as `shopping_list`. So you get the same thing.

Of course that isn't true as soon as you `print(x, y)` (which works, but prints a single 2-tuple value rather than two values in Python 2) or `print(x, file=sys.stderr)` (which is an error in Python 2).

---

`input` is another special case. This one wasn't designed to be compatible, you're just getting lucky here. Or maybe unlucky.

In Python 2, `input()` does `eval(raw_input())`—that is, it takes what you type and tries to evaluate it as Python source.

In Python 3, `input()` does what `raw_input()` did in Python 2—that is, it just returns a string.

So, the code sort of works in both, although you have to type `"DONE"` instead of just `DONE` in Python 2—just like you have to type `"DONE"` in your source code. Plus, of course, you can type `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')` in Python 2 and make yourself very sad. (This is why Python 2's `input` doesn't exist in Python 3.)

---

If you're asking why Python 3 was designed this way:

Once it was decided that some backward incompatibility was required in order to fix two decades of backlogged problems, there was a discussion about whether "Python 3000" should be intentionally incompatible to noisily break everything, or as compatible as possible (but no more so) to make migration easier.

The team decided on the latter. That included making some changes to Python 2.6 to make it easier to eventually migrate to 3.x, and some design decisions in Python 3.0 that were only made to make migration from 2.6 easier.

Once Python 3 got out into the wild, that turned out to be the right choice. To almost everyone's surprise, it was actually easier to write "dual-version" code (with the help of adapter libraries like `six`) than to write code that could be auto-transformed via `2to3` and `3to2`.

So they went even farther. Python 2.7 added a few features designed just for dual-version code, and they've continued to add things like the `u` string literal prefix (which does nothing in Python 3, but it's a way of making sure you have Unicode strings whether you run in 2.7 or 3.4) and `bytes.__mod__` (which allows Python 2 `%`-formatting code to continue to work in Python 3 in cases where you've deliberately chosen to keep things in `bytes`—e.g., parsing HTTP, where all you know is that it's some ASCII-compatible charset until you reach the `charset` header).

By the way, one of those "forward-compatibility" changes to Python 2 was the addition of `from __future__ import print_function`, which gives you Python 3-style `print`.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to `print`, Python3 made it a proper function, so you must call it with parentheses. In Python2, those parentheses are interpreted as "grouping" parenthesis rather than the start of a function call, so it makes no difference.

Python2: `print (1 + 2)` means, evaluate the expression `(1 + 2)` -> `print 3`

Python3: `print (1 + 2)` means evaluate the expression `1 + 2` and pass the result into the function `print` -> `print(3)`

Answer (score 1):

It ran because it is perfectly valid Python 2 code. However, `input` in Python 2 tries to evaluate the string that is input as a Python expression; the equivalent in Python 3 would be `eval(input("> "))`. Python 2 should always use `raw_input`, and Python 3 enforces that by getting rid of the old `input` behavior and renaming `raw_input` to `input`.

As for `print`, each of the items following the `print` keyword is an expression, and a valid expression can be wrapped in parentheses. `print('hello')` just prints the result of the expression `('hello')`, which is equivalent to the unparenthesized string `'hello'`; hence, `print('hello')` and `print 'hello'` are equivalent.

Note that `print 'hello',` and `print('hello',)`, however, would *not* be equivalent; the former prints the string `hello` with no line ending, while the latter prints the single-element tuple `(hello,)`. In Python 3, `print('hello',)` and `print('hello')` would be the same, since an argument list to a function call is allowed to have a trailing comma that gets ignored.

Answer (score -3):

You are not leveraging on the improvements of Python 3.

Hence it works (except with print) in Python 2